# Not able to make calls to mod_roster_odbc functions

Tags: configuration, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, rostering

I tried to use my own custom roster by integrating `mod_roster_odbc`. I changed the config file too (commented out `mod_roster` and make a new entry for `mod_roster_odbc`). After running with this setup, `mod_roster_odbc` module is getting started ( I put some logs to in start function, those I can see). But none of other function is not getting called as I alter presence or logged out/logged in.

Please help to identify where I am making the mistake.

Comment: Are you calling all ejabberd hooks needed, and well "connected" to functions in your module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know the answer to this. many websites tell you to use `mod_roster_odbc.erl` to create your own rostering. I believe thats your problem. Many of the functions are merged into `mod_roster.erl` file itself. I dont think this is mentioned anywhere.

So what you need to do is in `ejabberd.cfg` enable `mod_roster_odbc` but dont remove the `mod_roster.erl` file with the `odbc` file. This file will take care.

Finally you need to create a `rosterusers` table (or something like it) so that ejabber can query for friend list. After these changes, just restart ejabber server and you should be good to go. hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working absolutely perfect. This information is not updated anywhere.